# All my routes redirect to home page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

All my laravel routes keep redirecting back to the home page. For example when I go to `localhost:8000/about` it stays on the home page, `localhost:8000/about` shows up in the address bar but I'm still on the home page. I don't get an error. These last three (3) from this list redirect me to the home page:

```
<?php
//No auth needed to access these

Route::get('/course/detail/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@show',
    'as' => 'course.detail'
]);

Route::get('/{pagenum?}', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@showAll',
    'as' => 'courses'
]);

Route::get('/instructor/detail/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'InstructorController@showDetail',
    'as' => 'instructor.detail'
]);

Route::get('/about', function(){
    return view('frontend.about');
})->name('about');

Route::get('/contacts', function(){
    return view('frontend.contacts');
})->name('contacts');

Route::get('/search', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@search',
    'as' => 'courses.search'
]);
```

I have routes above these where you need to be authenticated before accessing and I can access them when logged in. You don't need to be logged in to access those above. From the six (6) I mentioned above I am able to access the first three (3) without being redirected. The other three (3) redirect me to the the home page with no error

I'm not new to Laravel, the routes were working before. What could be the cause of this redirecting?

Comment: are you using vue js or angular ? if so maybe they are conflicting with their routes

Comment: No, I am not using vue or angular @Hussein

Comment: Oh guess I've found Your problem, move last 3 routes above `/{pagenum?}` route since pagenum route is very wildcardy (:

Comment: @num8er that worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've issue with sequence of defining the routes.

You've defined:

```
Route::get('/{pagenum?}', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@showAll',
    'as' => 'courses'
]);
```

that acts like `/anything-that-comes-here`

and other route definitions for prefix `/` are being prevented by it.

so just move last 3 routes above of it:

```
Route::get('/about', function(){
    return view('frontend.about');
})->name('about');

Route::get('/contacts', function(){
    return view('frontend.contacts');
})->name('contacts');

Route::get('/search', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@search',
    'as' => 'courses.search'
]);

Route::get('/{pagenum?}', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@showAll',
    'as' => 'courses'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second route is the problem you have to place at the end:

```
Route::get('/{pagenum?}', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@showAll',
    'as' => 'courses'
]);
```